Find an azure resource group by wildcard using pulumi
I'm using pulumi with azure-native and not finding a way that I can query the subscription for resource groups using a wildcard.
The problem I'm trying to solve is needing to get resource keys (eg: storage) from another deployment to be used by the current deployment.
Using Pulumi AI and other searches, the results typically show:
const listResourceGroups = async () => {
const resourceGroups = await azureNative.resources.listResourceGroups();

resourceGroups.value.forEach(rg => {
    console.log(`Resource Group: ${rg.name}, Location: ${rg.location}`);
});

but listResourceGroups is not available
I've looked into the package and can find getResourceGroup, but this is not what I need.
Any alternatives ?

I found an answer via the Pulumi slack group here
But in case you cannot access: the summary:  No, list functions are not available in Pulumi SDKs. You can use a standard Azure SDK provided by Microsoft to do the search.
